# insert array value in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on insert array value in database in php using oops.I call a class on my form page .

```
<?php
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$ecode=$_POST['ecode'];  {these are my form value)
$rcode=$_POST['rcode'];
$dk=$_POST['dk'];
$qd=$_POST['qd'];
$tp=$_POST['tp'];
$vd=$_POST['vd'];
$valArr=array($pid,$ecode,$rcode,$dk,$qd,$tp,$vd);

if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])){
    $requester=new performance();
    $requester->addRow($valArr);
}
?>
```

and class performance code is

```
class performance extends DataAccess
{
    {
        $this->obj= new DataAccess;

    }
    function addRow($valArr)
    {
        foreach ($valArr as $key=>$value )

            $sql=   INSERT INTO employee_performance (id, empcode,review_emp_id,
                    subject_matter,quality_of_delivery, team_player,value_added)
                    VALUES $value
    }
    $sql=mysql_query($sql);
}
}
```

its can't insert all record in database.how I do this?

I want to know how can I insert this data in mysql database using foreach.

Comment: Dude...seriously? You think we can help you with a question "its show error , how can I solve this?" How about specifying the actual error?

Comment: Are the quotes missing due to pasting error or is this a bug in your class?

Comment: @Pateman BugS, BUGS. There are...many of them

Comment: Well I tried to edit this to be formatted but...just...I don't know...

Comment: zomfgwtf O_o !?.... Please, read tutorials on general programming, algorithms, security etc. and read resources on PHP first... :-/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

write like this

```
function addRow($valArr)
{
$values = implode(',',array_values($valArr));
$sql=  "INSERT INTO employee_performance (id, empcode, review_emp_id, subject_matter, quality_of_delivery, team_player,value_added) VALUES($values)";
$sql=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I think you need quotes around the elements. And quotes were missing from the query in the first post too.

Comment: can i put coloms name also in array

Comment: You should spell functions right, though. "implode()", not impload()

Answer (score 0):

Your code had more errors than I was able to count. However, this is a striped down and ugly/quick (hopefully working) edit:

```
<?php
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$ecode = $_POST['ecode'];
$rcode = $_POST['rcode'];
$dk = $_POST['dk'];
$qd = $_POST['qd'];
$tp = $_POST['tp'];
$vd = $_POST['vd'];

if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO employee_performance (id, empcode,review_emp_id,subject_matter,quality_of_delivery,team_player,value_added) VALUES ('$pid', '$ecode', '$rcode', '$dk', '$qd', '$tp', '$vd')";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```

Why would you insert it like a array like that? It does not make any sense? And your `$sql` is both the query and the execution of the query itself.

Comment: ALL PROject is made already in oops , so I am implementing a short part, I dont familiar more woth oops , but I cant do this directly

Answer (score 0):

Dear you are using simple single dimensional  array , there is no need for using foreach loop , because it will pick one value at a time, and only one value will be inserted in database , and then you can not insert value in same row.
just do this ...

```
if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])){
         $requester=new performance();
      $requester->addRow($_POST); // $_POST  is itself an associative array
   }


class performance extends DataAccess
     {
     {
     $this->obj= new DataAccess;

        }
     function addRow($valArr)
{
          extract($valArr);

           $sql=   INSERT INTO employee_performance (id, empcode,review_emp_id,                     subject_matter,quality_of_delivery, team_player,value_added)
      VALUES('$pid' , '$ecode'...'$vd');
     $sql=mysql_query($sql);
 }
 }
```